# SharePoint - Content Search WebPart not showing up

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I want the Content Search Webpart to display like this below.

[image]

But it's showing me this instead. 
[image]

Any idea why? i have de-activated and re-activated both the features for SharePoint Server Publishing and SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features. Still it does not show up what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

1.Go to SharePoint Central Admin found in your startup app windows

2.Go to Application Management and click on Manage service applications and click Search Service Application.

3.Go to Crawl rules and click New Crawl Rule and configure it

4.Go to Content Sources and click Start All Crawls